# How can the primary key be designated as this if it is not defined as column?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following SQLite query stored as a java string:

```
"CREATE TABLE " + Table_name + 
        "(" + Col_A + " TEXT, " + Col_B + " TEXT, " + 
        Col_C + " TEXT, " + "CONSTRAINT user_grp_id PRIMARY KEY " +
        "(" + Col_A + ", " + Col_B + ", " + Col_C + ")" +
        ")"
```

Where Table_name, Col_A, Col_B, Col_C are string variables.

My question is, if user_grp_id is not a column in the table, how can it be declared as the primary key?

Comment: It's not, it's the _name_ of the primary key you're creating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the name of the primary key, not the column itself. The columns come after the `PRIMARY KEY`

Comment: Is it possible to designate more than one column as a primary key?

Comment: Yes, that would be a `compound key`. Your example looks like it is creating a compound key based on Col_A, Col_B and Col_C